# Pandas Error Matching String

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have data like the SampleDf data below.  I'm trying to check values in one column in my dataframe to see if they contain 'sum' or 'count' or 'Avg' and then create a new column with the value 'sum', 'count', or 'Avg'.  When I run the code below on my real dataframe I'm getting the error below.  When I run dtypes on my real dataframe it says all the columns are objects.  The code below is related to the post below.  Unfortunately I don't get the same errors when I run the code on the SampleDf I've provided, but I couldn't post my whole dataframe.

post:
[Pandas and apply function to match a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724182/pandas-and-apply-function-to-match-a-string)

```
Code:

SampleDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom',"Avg(case when Value1 in ('Value2') and [DateType] in ('Value3') then LOS end)"],['bob',"isnull(Avg(case when XferToValue2 in (1) and DateType in ('Value3') and  [Value1] in ('HM') then  LOS end),0)"]],columns=['ReportField','OtherField'])


search1='Sum'
search2='Count'
search3='Avg'


def Agg_type(x):
    if search1 in x:
        return 'sum'
    elif search2 in x:
        return 'count'
    elif search3 in x:
        return 'Avg'
    else:
        return 'Other'

SampleDf['AggType'] = SampleDf['OtherField'].apply(Agg_type)

SampleDf.head()


Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a2b4920246a7> in <module>()
     17         return 'Other'
     18 
---> 19 SampleDf['AggType'] = SampleDf['OtherField'].apply(Agg_type)
     20 
     21 #SampleDf.head()

C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2292             else:
   2293                 values = self.asobject
-> 2294                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2295 
   2296         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)()

<ipython-input-17-a2b4920246a7> in Agg_type(x)
      8 
      9 def Agg_type(x):
---> 10     if search1 in x:
     11         return 'sum'
     12     elif search2 in x:

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with this data, though I can if I write over the `['OtherField']` column with a list of floats. Your function looks fine -- the problem appears to be with the dtype of your `['OtherField']` column.

Comment: is it okey if i provide a solution that works but that differs from yours ? simply because your code raised no error for me too

Comment: @RayhaneMama  Thank you for getting back to me, yes please provide your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SampleDf['new_col'] = np.where(SampleDf.OtherField.str.contains("Avg"),"Avg",
                          np.where(SampleDf.OtherField.str.contains("Count"),"Count",
                                  np.where(SampleDf.OtherField.str.contains("Sum"),"Sum","Nothing")))
```

please notice that this will work properly if you don't have both `Avg` and `Count` or `Sum` in the same string.
If you do, please notice me i'll look for a better approach.
Of course if something doesn't suit your needs also report it back.
Hope this was helpful

explanation:

what's happening is that you're looking for indexes where `Avg` is in the string inside `OtherField` column and fill `new_col` with "Avg" in these indexes. for the remaining fields( where there isn't "Avg", you look for `Count` and do the same and last you do the same for `Sum`.

documentation:

[np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

[pandas.series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.  Do you understand the difference between what my code was doing and what your code is doing?  I'm trying to understand why the pandas version didn't work.  I've looked at the data, it seems like strings not floats.

Comment: yeah actually i got that bug a couple of times me too, i'm not sure why it pops however, printing df.dtypes shows that i don't have floats but well.. i'm still looking for the cause however, i'll keep you notified @ndderwerdo

Comment: @ndderwerdo i just tested your code and it works, so if it still doesn't work for you i don't think it's related to the code you posted.